# Which version of jboss EAP supports IBM MQ 9.0.0.5?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, ibm-mq

Can some one please help me out to know is IBM MQ 9.0.0.5 is supported by jboss 7.1 or not? if not which JBOSS EAP has the support for IBM MQ 9.0.0.5.

- IBM MQ 9.0.0.5 support starts from which version of JBOSS EAP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JBoss EAP 7.1 Supported Configurations](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2026253#EAP_71) IBM MQ 8.0 is certified!
As far as I know, IBM MQ 9.0 certification, is planned for JBoss EAP 7.2